# Charts on a $\mathcal C^k$ manifold are $\mathcal C^k$-diffeomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a $\mathcal C^k$ manifold of dimension $d$ and $\mathcal A=\{(U_i,\varphi_i)_{i\in I}\}$ be an altas on $M$. Is it correct to assume that the charts $(\varphi_i)_{i\in I}$ are $\mathcal C^k$-diffeomorphisms? We can use the characterization that a function $f:M\longrightarrow\mathbb R^d$ is  $\mathcal C^k$ iff $\exists(V,\psi)\in\mathcal A$ such that $f\circ\psi^{-1}$ is a $\mathcal C^k$-diffeomorphism. Since we know that the charts are compatible, then for any charts $\varphi_i$,$ \varphi_j$, $\varphi_i\circ\varphi_j^{-1}$ is a $\mathcal C^k$-diffeomorphism. We thus find that any chart $\varphi_i$ is $\mathcal C^k$ and is by definition invertible and by a similar reasoning, we get that $\varphi_i^{-1}$ is also $\mathcal C^k$. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Sure, the transition maps are $C^k$ diffeos essentially by definition.

Comment: Before the chart maps are charts, it does not make sense to talk about "diffeomorphisms". Once they have been declared to be charts (satisfying all the necessary conditions), they are tautologically diffeomorphisms.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answers. The reason why I asked this question is because in the course I am studying, charts are supposed only to be homeomorphisms

Comment: Well sure, because a diffeomorphism requires smooth structure which requires smooth chart maps, so it would be self-referential to define the maps as diffeomorphisms

Comment: That they end up being diffeomorphisms is actually rather useful in proofs, as tautological as it is. For example, when proving a map a map is a diffeomorphism you can consider its action on charts using the fact a composition of diffeos is a diffeo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $M$ be a $\mathcal C^k$ manifold of dimension $d$ and $\mathcal A=\{(U_i,\varphi_i)_{i\in I}\}$ be an atlas on $M$. Is it correct to assume that the charts $(\varphi_i)_{i\in I}$ are $\mathcal C^k$-diffeomorphisms?

That charts are $\mathcal C^k$-diffeomorphisms cannot be an *assumption* in the definition of charts. This would not make any sense at the beginning because it is not yet clear what $\mathcal C^k$ means in this general context.

In a comment you write

> The reason why I asked this question is because in the course I am studying, charts are supposed only to be homeomorphisms.

Correct, in the first instance a chart is only a homeomorphism. But in a $\mathcal C^k$ atlas $\mathcal A$ the charts satisfy certain compatibility conditions which allow to extend the concept of $\mathcal C^k$ maps in the classical sense (dealing only with maps between open subsets of Euclidean spaces) to maps between $\mathcal C^k$  manifolds. With this extended concept charts in $\mathcal A$ can in fact be *proved* to be diffeomorphisms (as you do). Let us emphasize

- Not every chart on $M$ becomes a diffeomorphism; *which charts* depends on the given $\mathcal C^k$ atlas $\mathcal A$.
- It requires a carefully considered *concept* of $\mathcal C^k$ for maps between manifolds with $\mathcal C^k$ atlases before it makes sense to say that charts in  $\mathcal A$ are diffeomorphisms. Such a concept is not available at the time when a $\mathcal C^k$ atlas $\mathcal A$ is defined.

Let me try to explain it in  more detail.

In multivariable calculus one defines what it means that a function $f : U \to V$ between open subsets $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $V \subset \mathbb R^m$  is $\mathcal C^k$. This allows to define the concept of a $\mathcal C^k$ diffeomorphism, but this concept is of course limited to functions between open subsets of Euclidean spaces.

An $n$-dimensional topological manifold $M$ is a topological space which *looks locally like $\mathbb R^n$* (and satisfies some other technical conditions). Looking locally like $\mathbb R^n$ means that each $p \in M$ has an open neighborhood which is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. This gives rise to introduce the  concept of a *chart on $M$*: This is a pair $(U,\phi)$ consisting of an open $U \subset M$ and a homeomorphism $\phi : U \to U'$ to an open subset $U' \subset \mathbb R^n$. A *topological atlas on $M$* is a collection of charts whose domains cover $M$.  Taking *all charts* gives the maximal topological atlas on $M$.

Given a map $f : M \to \mathbb R^m$, we can say that $f$ is $\mathcal C^k$ with respect to a chart $(U,\phi)$ if $f \circ \phi^{-1} : U' \to \mathbb R^m$ is $\mathcal C^k$ in the sense of multivariable calculus. Let us emphasize that this depends on the chart; for some charts $f \circ \phi^{-1}$ may be $\mathcal C^k$, for other charts this may fail.

Similarly, given a map $\mu : W' \to M$ defined on an open $W' \subset \mathbb R^m$, we can say that $\mu$ is $\mathcal C^k$ with respect to a chart $(U,\phi)$ if $\phi \circ \mu : W' \cap \mu^{-1}(U) \to U'$ is $\mathcal C^k$ in the sense of multivariable calculus. Again this depends on the chart.

Thus for a topological manifold $M$ we are not able to give an "absolute definition" for maps $f : M \to \mathbb R^m$ and $\mu : W' \to M$ being $\mathcal C^k$. We can only define $f$ and $\mu$ to be $\mathcal C^k$ with respect to a given *topological atlas $\mathcal A$ on $M$* in the sense that $f \circ \phi^{-1} : U' \to \mathbb R^m$ and $\phi \circ \mu : W' \cap \mu^{-1}(U) \to U'$ are $\mathcal C^k$ for all charts in $\mathcal A$.

It is moreover desirable to work with a **fixed** topological atlas $\mathcal A$ on $M$ which determines whether *any* given $f : M \to \mathbb R^m$ is $\mathcal C^k$ and whether *any* given $\mu: W' \to M$ is $\mathcal C^k$; and more generally, whether any given $g : W \to \mathbb R^m$ defined on an open subset $W \subset M$ and any given $\mu : W' \to W$ are $\mathcal C^k$ with respect to the induced atlas $\mathcal A \cap W  = \{(U \cap W, \phi \mid_{U \cap W}) \mid (U,\phi) \in \mathcal A \}$.

The atlas $\mathcal A$ has the property that for each chart $(U,\phi) \in \mathcal A$ the maps $\phi : U \to U'$ and $\phi^{-1} : U' \to U$ are $\mathcal C^k$ with respect to $(U,\phi)$: Simply observe that $\phi \circ \phi^{-1} = id_{U'}$. But this does not mean that they are $\mathcal C^k$ with respect to $\mathcal A$ since this depends also on the other charts in $\mathcal A$.

An obvious requirement is that $\phi$ and $ \phi^{-1}$ should be $\mathcal C^k$ with respect to $\mathcal A$. It is easy to see that this requirement is equivalent to the following:

For any two charts $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$, the transition functions

$$\psi \circ \phi^{-1} : \phi(U \cap V ) \to  U \cap V \to \psi (U \cap V)$$
$$\phi \circ \psi^{-1} : \psi(U \cap V ) \to  U \cap V \to \phi(U \cap V)$$
are $\mathcal C^k$  in the sense of multivariable calculus. If  $\mathcal A$ has this property, it is called a *$\mathcal C^k$ atlas* on $M$.

For a $\mathcal C^k$ atlas $\mathcal A$ all maps $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ determined by the charts in  $\mathcal A$ are $\mathcal C^k$ diffeomorphisms - but not in an absolute sense, it depends on the atlas $\mathcal A$. With respect to another $\mathcal C^k$ atlas on $M$ they may be no longer $\mathcal C^k$.

In that sense it is *tautological* to say that $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ are $\mathcal C^k$ diffeomorphisms. But we must be aware that this simple statement is based on the preceding development of a whole theory of $\mathcal C^k$ manifolds and $\mathcal C^k$ maps.