# Motivation for Lee's definition of smooth map

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

I am trying to understand why Lee makes the following definition for real valued smooth maps on manifolds.

> Let M be a topological manifold. We call $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ smooth if chart for $p \in M$,  $(U, \varphi)$, satisfies the condition $f \circ \varphi^{-1} : \varphi(U) \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth in the usual way.

What bugs me is that, definition says that function is smooth if behavior of it on a homeomorphic image of the local domain is smooth, but somehow it feels like instead of homeomorphic, the word should be diffeomorphic even though it is yet to be defined.

How does homeomorphism (the local coordinate map) not make 'smoothness' be lost a bit? I mean, how do we guarantee it? I suppose transition map being smooth was the way to guarantee it, but maybe I can get some more intuition into it.

PS: I guess one possible answer is that this is just a definition, but then how this was natural definition is not clear to me, as I would be puzzled seeing just availability of continuous map.

To add an example, I would like to think of graph of $\vert x\vert$ around $0$ as my manifold $M$, open space homeomorphic to $M$ as $(-1,1)$ and the map whose smoothness is to be determined to be $id$ and the local coordinate map to be projection to x coordinate $\pi$. I have seen some authors, e.g Kristopher Tapp, to define a map to be smooth on a closed set if it can be extended to a smooth map on a open set containing the initial domain. In this case $id$
is smooth on whole Euclidean space. But under this definiton $id$ is smooth iff $\pi^{-1}$ is smooth which is not.

Thus I am confused if there are many ways to capture 'smoothness' which are not necessarily same but depend on definition, which is a bit unsatisfactory since 'continuity' was captured by topology unambiguously.

Comment: You must have copied Lee’s definition wrong.

Comment: More or less the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4562258.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map $\varphi$ associated to a chart $(U,\varphi)$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image. However, one cannot say that before one has defined a smooth map (therefore before defining diffeomorphism)!

It seems to me that you are worried about the idea that the chart map need only be a homeomorphism, rather than a diffeomorphism. Let's take your example, the graph $\Gamma=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|y=|x|\}$. We can define a chart $(U,\varphi)$ with $U=\Gamma$ and $\varphi:(x,y)\mapsto x$. With this atlas, $\Gamma$ is diffeomorphic to $(-1,1)$.... But, $\Gamma$ is not diffeomorphic to $(-1,1)$, right? Well, here we need to be more careful. There are two different differential structures on $\Gamma$ in question:

1. there is the induced structure via the embedding of this graph into $\mathbb{R}^2$;
2. there is a structure induced by this chart.

These two are not the same differential structure, so they define different notions of smooth map on your manifold. In fact, according to the first, this is not a manifold!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Joshua Tilley's explanation, the specific point of confusion for your question seems to lie in the statement:

"What bugs me is that, definition says that function is smooth if behavior of it on a homeomorphic image of the local domain is smooth"

NO, this definition is not saying that. It is saying that for an arbitrary ***chart*** $\phi$ for $p$, $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ will be smooth.  The key distinction is that most homeomorphisms are not charts.  Your smooth structure is defined by an arbitrarily chosen special class of mutually compatible homeomorphisms, wherein charts $\phi$ and $\psi$ are compatible with each other if $\phi\circ\psi^{-1}$ is smooth where it is defined.

Most local homeomorphisms will not be compatible with your chosen class of charts, and will therefore not be charts themselves. The definition is asking you only to ensure $f$ is smooth when composed with a chart.

Comment: I am confused. I can point 1 issue in which yes not every homeomorphism is a chart, because charts have images that are open in some R^n and n here should be same as 'dimension' of image. e.g ig if you map surface of sphere to a random linear hyperplane in R^3 this is not technically a chart. But, other than this a chart is just a homeomorphism according to Lee on pg4.

Comment: It seems you are saying a homeomorphism is a chart if it is compatible with the charts used to define the smooth structure (ref 'Most local ... themselves') but ig what you mean is 'smooth chart' . If I correctly understood, initially we define a smooth structure. Now this smooth structure excludes some of the local charts to be 'smooth' because they may not be compatible with initial charts.

Comment: Just one question, then a given function can be smooth in a given structure but not smooth for another given structure?

Comment: Yes, Mahammad, whether a function is smooth or not depends on the differential structure. A function certainly can be smooth w.r.t. one structure and not another.

Comment: @MahammadYusifov yes, here the author is certainly referring to what you might call “smooth charts”.  I don’t have the source text but ideally the author should clarify in his definition of a chart what he means.  But yes your other comments are on point.  And yes, a “chart” in the sense of a local homeo can be smooth for one structure but not another.  Indeed, every self homeomorphism of $\mathbb R$ determines a chart for some smooth structure, but two different homeos aren’t smooth relative to the other’s structure unless one is a diffeomorphism composed with the other